# Prove or disprove: $A\subset B$ $\Rightarrow$ acc$(A)\subset$ acc$(B)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove or disprove: a. $A\subset B$ $\Rightarrow$ acc$(A)\subset$ acc$(B)$ where acc$(X)$ is the set of accumulation points of the set $X$.

b. $\sup A \in \text{acc}(A)$.

The answers say both are incorrect. I can't figure out why.
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: For b. consider a set containing just one elenment. Yet a. seems strange to me.

Comment: How do you define an accumulation point?

Comment: $a$ is an accumulation point of the set $X$ if in any neighborhood of $a$ there is infinitely many points in $X$, or at least one point in a punctured area of $a$.

Comment: Thank you for b. quid. Wouldn't have thought of how simple it it.

Answer (score 1):

a. Let $x \in acc(A)$

Then, there exists a sequence $\lbrace x_n \rbrace \subset A $ s.t. $x_n \to x$ and $\forall_{ n \in \mathbb{N}} \quad x_n \neq x $ .

Since $A \subset B$ we have : $\lbrace x_n \rbrace \subset B $ and $ x_n \to x$ and $\forall_{ n \in \mathbb{N}} \quad x_n \neq x $

Therefore $x \in acc(B) $

b. $ A=\lbrace a \rbrace $

EDIT: there was a mistake pointed out in the comments below

Comment: I say both are true

Comment: But if I have a singleton $A=\{a\}$ then $a=\sup A$ but acc$(A)=\emptyset$, isn't that so?

Comment: $ acc ( \lbrace a \rbrace )=\lbrace a \rbrace $

Comment: But if we take a punctured neighborhood of $a$ there is no element in the neighborhood that is in $a$, and there there is no infinite number of elements in $A$ for sure...

Comment: Meit is correct. If we have a finite set $S$, then $\operatorname{acc}(S)=\emptyset$.

Comment: No, you are right. I was using a different definition. $a \in acc(A) \quad iff \quad \exists_{ \lbrace a_n \rbrace } s.t. a_n \to a $ but in your definition there is also a condition that $ \forall_{ n \in \mathbb{N} } \quad a_n \neq a $ So, the second is incorrect, but for the first one the proof holds, but there should be a comment that $ x_n \neq x $

Answer (score 0):

I think part $a)$ is true if $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $A\subset B\subset \mathbb{R}$, and $x$ is a limit point of $A$. Then, for $\delta >0$, $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap A\setminus \{x\}$ is nonempty by definition of limit point.

Then $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap A\setminus\{x\}\subset (x-\delta,x+\delta) \cap B\setminus\{x\}$, and we know that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap A\setminus\{x\}$ is nonempty, so $(x-\delta,x+\delta) \cap B\setminus\{x\}$ is nonempty as well.